# IE10/Win 7 ignores CSS keyframes when within a media query?

Tags: internet-explorer, css, css-animations

0I'm working on some CSS animations for a web app with a responsive layout. Some of my animation adjusts the width of some containers and position of a background image. As a result I have something like this (prefixes omitted for brevity):

```
/* Default styles */

.box { animation: grow 1s ease; }

keyframes grow {
    0% {
        width: 100px;
    }
    100% {
        width: 200px;
    }
}

/* Large display styles */

@media (min-width: 1200px){

   keyframes grow {
       0% {
          width: 200px;
       }
       100% {
           width: 300px;
       }
   }

}
```

According to this post on [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/20572/ie10-css-animation-issue/p1), IE10 on Win7 ignores keyframes within media queries. I have tested the theory and found it to be true.

Anyone found a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about reorganizing the code like following?

```
.box { animation: grow 1s ease; }

@keyframes grow {
    0% {
        width: 100px;
    }
    100% {
        width: 200px;
    }
}

@keyframes growLarge {
    0% {
        width: 200px;
    }
    100% {
        width: 300px;
    }
}

/* Large display styles */

@media (min-width: 1200px){

   .box { animation: growLarge 1s ease; }

}
```

Comment: That would be the best way to handle it IMHO.

Comment: This was my initial solution. I like it as it's all CSS but it does mean a lot of extra CSS given the number of animations I have to duplicate. Probably the best way though!

Answer (score 0):

I would use Javascript for this. Here is some pseudo code, not sure it works in IE:

```
if (screen.width > 1200) {

   // Large display styles

  var grow = 'keyframes grow { 0% { width: 100px; } 100% { width: 200px; } }',
      head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
      style = document.createElement('style');

    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(grow));

}
```

So, detect a screen size bigger then 1200 in Javascript and append a new style. Also if you know your keyframes grow stylesheet index and rule index you could just modify it trough CSSOM.

Answer (score 0):

Would using `.box { transition: all 1s ease }` outside of mediaqueries work? And then just change the width with media queries